# jq 1.5 multiple bash variables as argument

Tags: sh, posix, jq

I'm working on a script for my openwrt, a watchdog for my pia connection. I'm trying to make this little jq filter but every time I try I get error
I've more options and I "compose" the jq filter

```
all_region_data=$(curl -s "https://serverlist.piaservers.net/vpninfo/servers/v4" | head -1)
BestRegion="italy"

jq_filter='.regions[]'

if [ -z "$BestRegion" ]; then # BestRegion not forced
    if [ "$pia_pf" = "true" ]; then
        jq_filter="${jq_filter} | select(.port_forward==true)"
    fi

    if [ "$pia_no_geo" = "false" ]; then
        jq_filter="${jq_filter} | select(.geo==false)"
    fi

    if [ "$pia_no_geo" = "true" ]; then
        jq_filter="${jq_filter} | select(.geo==true)"
    fi

    jq_filter="${jq_filter} | .servers.meta[0].ip+\" \"+.id+\" \"+.name+\" \"+(.geo|tostring)"

    summarized_region_data=$(echo "$all_region_data" | jq -r "${jq_filter}")

    best_region # function to extract best_region

    if [ -z "$BestRegion" ]; then
        log "..."
        log "No region responded within ${max_latency}s, consider using a higher timeout."
        rm -rf "$wg_script_lock_file"
        return
    fi
else # BestRegion forced
    if [ "$pia_pf" = "true" ]; then
        jq_filter="${jq_filter} | select(.port_forward==true)"
    fi

    if [ "$pia_no_geo" = "false" ]; then
        jq_filter="${jq_filter} | select(.geo==false)"
    fi

    if [ "$pia_no_geo" = "true" ]; then
        jq_filter="${jq_filter} | select(.geo==true)"
    fi
fi
```

The first `if cycle` works, the function do the dirty works. But I want to have the opportunity to "force" the `BestRegion` so I created the `else cycle`. Here I've the problem!

This's what I'm trying to do

```
echo $all_region_data | jq --arg REGION_ID "$BestRegion" --arg JQ_FILTER "$jq_filter" -r '$JQ_FILTER | select(.id==$REGION_ID)'
```

I can't use these two `var`, I get this error

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): Cannot index string with string "id"
```

How would you do it?

Comment: The invocation `jq --arg REGION_ID "$BestRegion" --arg JQ_FILTER "$jq_filter" -r $JQ_FILTER | select(.id==$REGION_ID)'` is quite muddled.   Pay close attention to the distinction between shell variables and jq variables. And don't forget that if you set X=.a in the shell, then `jq --arg x "$X" '$x'` would print the JSON string `".a"`

Comment: I can reorder the variables in order to have the first `arg` the jq_filter and the second the region_id. I can also change the var name to make sure to don't make any mistakes. All works If I use only one `arg` but I need two. I need a non JSON output, so I used `-r` option in jq, is right I think. I think the problem is with `"` and `'` but I don't know how to handle this, I tried many variations without luck

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, the problem you're looking for help with is this:

You have a shell variable `$jq_filter` that contains the text of a JQ filter. You have a shell variable `$BestRegion` that contains a plain text string. You want to pass the former in as part of a larger JQ filter while passing the latter in as a JQ variable.

Try:

```
jq --arg REGION_ID "$BestRegion" "$jq_filter"'| select(.id==$REGION_ID)'
```

Specifically, you want the *shell* to expand `$jq_filter` before passing it to JQ, so you put it in double quotes, but you want *JQ* to process `$REGION_ID` so you keep it in single quotes. Note that there is no space between the double quote and the single quote - this ensures the shell combines both strings together as one argument to JQ.

Comment: Yes, in my bash script I want to pass 2 variables, jq_filter that contain the entire filter that is "built" from various options and BestRegion that contain a plain text. My first thought was to pass 2 arg but I had expansion problems. If needed I can modify the single/double quotes for the vars, but I'll try this