# Assign jq command to a variable and process the variable in later variables

Tags: shell, jq

```
kubectl get service boss-gateway -n boss-system -o json \
| jq ' (.metadata.labels.boss, .spec.selector.boss)|="internal-gateway"
| (.metadata.annotations["service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal"]) |= "true" ' \
| kubectl apply -f - --dry-run=client -o yaml
```

I have other queries as well, which use this snippet

| jq ' (.metadata.labels.boss, .spec.selector.boss)|="internal-gateway"
| (.metadata.annotations["service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal"]) |= "true" '

can i assign to a variable and use back in my bash script?

I tried like this

export test="jq ' (.metadata.labels.istio, .spec.selector.istio)|="internal-ingressgateway"'"

kubectl get service boss-gateway -n boss-system -o json 
| ${test} 
| kubectl apply -f - --dry-run=client -o yaml
when i echoed, it is showing correctly and i am able to execute that query
but when i try to run it in the script, it is not working. any idea, where am i missing?

Comment: Have you tried putting $test in quotes?

Answer (score 0):

The kind of programming you seem to aspire to is possible but usually not worth the effort, if only because of the way you typically get tangled in your own web.  If you want to go down this path, then consider this attempt of yours:

> export test="jq '(.metadata.labels.istio, .spec.selector.istio)|="internal-ingressgateway"'"

To make this work, you'll have to escape the inner double-quotation marks:

```
export test="jq '(.metadata.labels.istio, .spec.selector.istio)|=\"internal-ingressgateway\"'"
```

For further inspiration, see
[jq 1.5 multiple bash variables as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64937500/jq-1-5-multiple-bash-variables-as-argument)